# Change account on Linux Dropbox?

Tags: linux, debian, dropbox

I'm running Crunchbang (Debian-based) and I [installed Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) using the `.deb` package.

When the program started I logged into an account, but now I want to log out and sign in to another account.

The only possible interface to Dropbox that I have is the `dropbox` command on the terminal, but it doesn't have an option to change account.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to rename the dropbox folders:

```
killall dropbox
mv ~/Dropbox ~/Dropbox-user1
mv ~/.dropbox ~/.dropbox-user1
```

Then restart dropbox and set up the new account.

Then you could have a small script that switched between the two by stopping, renameing and starting dropbox.

Comment: Didn't work, never asked me for the new account info

Comment: Yeah, you have to run `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` after to have it ask. But the other answer where you unlink it on their website is more proper. But I'm too lazy to go to their website, so I did this.

Answer (score 18):

Go to dropbox account at https://www.dropbox.com

Security tab: unlink machine.

After that you can restart dropbox at linux machine - it will ask to link again.

```
killall dropbox
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Comment: This seems like the more "correct" way to do it

Answer (score 1):

I just did this on my Chromebook: rename the Dropbox folder in Files. I immediately got a pop-up telling me the folder was moved or renamed and to click here to reconnect. I was then taken to the Dropbox site where I was able to connect a different account. Almost too easy.